# Image Template matching in android using openCV

Tags: android, image, opencv

I am trying to make an automation android applicaton which finds an image(template/subimage) inside another image(main/bigger image).

[image: OnePlus 3T menu image]

[image: Whatsapp icon image from MotG 3]

Menu image is from onePlus 3T.
Whatsapp icon image is from motoG 3.

I have tried to find whatsapp image from oneplus 3T in its menu image and it was successfully found.

But, when i am trying to find some subimage from different device of different screensize, it is not working.

Can someone please help. Below is the code I am using.

```
class MatchingDemo {
public Mat run(Mat img, Mat templ, String outFile, int match_method) {
    System.out.println("\nRunning Template Matching");

    // / Create the result matrix
    int result_cols = img.cols() - templ.cols() + 1;
    int result_rows = img.rows() - templ.rows() + 1;
    Mat result = new Mat(result_rows, result_cols, CvType.CV_32FC1);

    // / Do the Matching and Normalize
    Imgproc.matchTemplate(img, templ, result, match_method);
    Core.normalize(result, result, 0, 1, Core.NORM_MINMAX, -1, new Mat());

    // / Localizing the best match with minMaxLoc
    MinMaxLocResult mmr = Core.minMaxLoc(result);

    Point matchLoc;
    if (match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF || match_method == Imgproc.TM_SQDIFF_NORMED) {
        matchLoc = mmr.minLoc;
    } else {
        matchLoc = mmr.maxLoc;
    }

    System.out.println("matchloc.x "+ matchLoc.x);
    System.out.println("templ.cols "+ templ.cols());
    System.out.println("matchloc.y "+ matchLoc.y);
    System.out.println("templ.rows "+ templ.rows());

    // / Show me what you got
    Imgproc.rectangle(img, matchLoc, new Point(matchLoc.x + templ.cols(),
            matchLoc.y + templ.rows()), new Scalar(0, 255, 0), 20);

    // Save the visualized detection.
    System.out.println("Writing "+ outFile);
    Imgcodecs.imwrite(outFile, img);



    return img;
}
```

}

Comment: Please show the code you are using ? Also Template matching would be more accurate, if you strip the text *WhatsApp* from the template image, as the Fonts may vary along various devices.

Comment: Hi @ZdaR .. I have edited the question including my code for image detection.

Comment: Have you tried the suggestion to remove *WhatsApp* text from the template image ?

Comment: Yes, I tried your suggestion..It's not working as well.

Comment: If you know the size of the screen which the template was taken and the size of the screen where image was taken, you can try to resize the image in the same ration. I mean pixel size. Let's say the template image was taken from an image with pixel size of 640x 480 and then if you try to look it one of 320x240, the template needs to be resized with a factor of 0.5. in both dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

I cropped the template image from your given snapshot and everything worked fine:

- New template Image:

[image]

Code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np


img_1 = cv2.imread("path/to/snapshot", 0)
img_rgb = cv2.imread("path/to/snapshot")
template_img = cv2.imread("path/to/template", 0)

h, w = template_img.shape

res = cv2.matchTemplate(img_1, template_img, cv2.TM_CCOEFF)
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)

cv2.rectangle(img_rgb, max_loc, (max_loc[0]+w, max_loc[1]+h), np.array([0, 0, 255]), 3)

cv2.imwrite("./debug.png", img_rgb)
```

Output:

[image]

**Note:** `matchTemplate` is a very basic implementation, to get more scale invariant results you may try with [SIFT features](https://docs.opencv.org/3.3.0/da/df5/tutorial_py_sift_intro.html)